# ¿Porque tengo este error al ocultar este MenuItem?

Tags: android, navigationview

estoy haciendo una aplicación en android donde tengo 2 `Activities` una es el menu principal y la otra es una pantalla de logueo, Para acceder a la actividad de logueo tengo un menu lateral cun un `MenuItem` que pone Log In, despues de loguearme y recibir el resultado de la `Activity` quiero que este se oculte y se muertre otro `MenuItem` para desloguearse, pero me sale un error de `NullPointedException` al intentar usar los metodos `.setVisible()` por lo que entiendo que el `.findViewById()` que uso para asociarlos los elementos creados en XML no esta funcionando, pero no se porque ni como puedo solucionarlo, adjunto el fragmento de codigo

Codigo del onActivityResult() donde intento ocultar un `MenuItem` y mostrar el otro

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == USERNAME_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        MenuItem logInItem = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.nav_manage);
        MenuItem logOutItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_closeSession);
        logInItem.setVisible(false);  //Error aqui
        logOutItem.setVisible(true);
        user = data.getStringExtra("user");
        Log.d("Volviendo al Main ",user);
        presentarUrls(savedState,drawer);
        subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        subtitle.setText(user);
    }
}
```

Archivo XML donde defino los items del menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="Settings">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Login" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_closeSession"
            android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
            android:title="Log Out"
            android:visible="false"></item>
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Notifications">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Notifications" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Y el codigo de Error que me saca Android Studio

```
Process: es.app.appff, PID: 17667
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=es.app.appfff/.Login (has extras) }} to activity {es.app.appfff/es.app.appfff.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, he encontrado la solución a mi problema, con un menu lateral me referia a un `NavigationView`, simplemente tenia que usar el metodo `NavigationView.getMenu()` para sacar el Menu donde estarian los items y buscarlos

Primero, Instancio el `NavigationView` y lo asocio con su recurso XML

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Despues ya puedo sacar el menu de items del `NavigationView`

```
Menu nav_menu = navigationView.getMenu();
```

A continuacion de ese menu de items puedo sacar los items segun sus IDs en los recursos XML

```
MenuItem logInItem = nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_manage);
MenuItem logOutItem = nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_closeSession);
```

Answer (score 2):

Los objetos del menú no debes buscarlos con findViewById. Lo que puedes hacer es volver a crear el menú llamando a invalidateOptionsMenu(), que hará que se ejecute otra vez el método onCreateOptionsMenu y ahí sí vas a tener todos los objetos del menú para hacer con ellos lo que quieras.

Comment: Mejora la respuesta aportando un pequeño ejemplo con código

Comment: Vale, ahora he intentado conseguir los objetos en ese metodo, pero me dice que no tal como lo hago.

`@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem logOutItem = menu.getItem(R.id.nav_closeSession);
        MenuItem logInItem = menu.getItem(R.id.nav_manage);
    }`

Comment: Vale, es una tonteria XD escribia el codigo despues del return, funciona a la perfección cambiando eso, gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Mira una cosa que yo hago es después de popular o inflar mi menú obtengo los items de dicho menú y los guardo como atributo en mi actividad para luego utilizarlos cuando necesite y me ha funcionado de maravilla puedes hacer algo como esto en tu caso.

```
MenuItem logInItem;
MenuItem logOutItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_prueba, menu);

    logInItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_manage);
    logOutItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_closeSession);

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Para asegurarse que lo vuelva a crear

    /** Utilizas los items como te quieras **/
    logInItem.setVisible(false);
    logOutItem.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Hago tal cual lo que explicas, el programa ejecuta el `onCreateOptionsMenu` , pero creo que no consigo los `MenuItems` porque intento cambiarle el titulo al `MenuItem` y no se cambia `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            Log.d("Marca","Pasa por onCreateOptionsMenu");
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
            logInItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_manage);
            logInItem.setTitle("Texto cambiado");
            logOutItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_closeSession);
            return true;
    }`

Comment: no te preocupes lo que sucede es tu tienes un sub menu `settingsItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_settings);
logInItem = (MenuItem) settingsItem.getSubMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_manage);` pero en tu xml del menu agregale al item de settings el id "nav_settings" y listo basicamente primero obtienes el item del primer nivel y luego el item del segundo nivel osea los items de tu submenu del item settings.